# Fill data into Model Form Django and pass id paramater in URL Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying fill data into model form and load pages with information field of object. However, I get some error and I don't know fix

## views.py

```
def profile(request, id):
user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
user_info = get_object_or_404(UserInfor, user_id=user.id)
user_form = UserForm(instance=user)
profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=user_info)
return render(request, 'pages/profile.html', {'user': user_form, 'user_info': profile_form})
```

## urls.py

```
path('profile/id=<int:id>/', views.profile, name='profile')
```

## profile.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="form" method="post" action="{% url 'profile' %}">
```

Error I got

```
NoReverseMatch at /profile/id=2/
Reverse for 'profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: 
['profile\\/id\\=(?P<id>[0-9]+)\\/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/id%3D2/
Django Version: 2.2.1
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: 
['profile\\/id\\=(?P<id>[0-9]+)\\/$']
Exception Location: F:\FTEL_CSOC\env\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 668
Python Executable:  F:\FTEL_CSOC\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Path:    
['F:\\FTEL_CSOC\\webping',
'F:\\FTEL_CSOC\\webping',
'F:\\FTEL_CSOC\\webping',
'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 
2019.1.1\\helpers\\pycharm_display',
'F:\\FTEL_CSOC\\env\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
'C:\\Users\\vuthe\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
'C:\\Users\\vuthe\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\vuthe\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
'F:\\FTEL_CSOC\\env',
'F:\\FTEL_CSOC\\env\\lib\\site-packages',
'F:\\FTEL_CSOC\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.6.egg',
'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
'2019.1.1\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
 Server time:   Mon, 24 Jun 2019 07:29:28 +0000
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?
I tried to fix link suggestion but result is not found page

Comment: Why do you have that bizarre format? You should format your URLs as `/profile/2/`, not `/profile/id=2/`.

Comment: I formatted as /profile/2/ but profile.html isn't loaded

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `id` in your profile URL reversal in `views.py`. Try something like this:

```
{% url 'profile' id=user.id %}
```

Comment: page not found, what do I have to?

Comment: You have two lines for possible 404: `user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
user_info = get_object_or_404(UserInfor, user_id=user.id)` @ItachiUchiha